# Apache Spark making request for data enrichment

Tags: java, http, apache-spark, asynchronous

Im pretty new to apache spark. I would like to get some guidance on if this is bad practice for a Apache spark job

The goal is to make requests out to a external rest api and join in the response while processing data. This needs to be able to handle thousands of requests. I am trying to make async http request and return the http responses as a RDD.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do

```
public final class AsyncSparkJob implements Serializable {

// Java-friendly version of SparkContext
// Used to return JavaRDDs and works with Java Collections.
private static JavaSparkContext sc;
// AsyncSparkJob - constructor
public AsyncSparkJob(JavaSparkContext sc) {
    // initialize the spark context
    this.sc = sc;
}

// run - execute the spark transformations and actions
public void run(String filePath ) {
    System.out.println("Starting spark job");
    JavaRDD<String> inputFile = this.sc.textFile(filePath);
    // Send a partition of http requests to each executor
    Long results = inputFile.mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, HttpResponse>(){
        // call - FlatMapFunction call implementation
        public Iterator<HttpResponse> call(Iterator<String> stringIterator) throws Exception {
            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setSocketTimeout(300000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(300000).build();

            CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setMaxConnTotal(500).setMaxConnPerRoute(500)
                    .build();
            httpClient.start();
            List<HttpResponse> httpResponseList = new LinkedList<HttpResponse>();
            try {
                List<Future<HttpResponse>> futureResponseList = new LinkedList<Future<HttpResponse>>();
                // As long as we have values in the Iterator keep looping
                while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
                    String uri = stringIterator.next();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
                    Future<HttpResponse> futureResponse = httpClient.execute(request, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
                        public void completed(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                            System.out.println("Completed request");
                        }

                        public void failed(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("failed" + e);
                        }

                        public void cancelled() {
                            System.out.println("cancelled");
                        }
                    });
                    futureResponseList.add(futureResponse);
                }
                // Now that we have submitted all of the responses we can start
                // looking threw and trying to read the response.
                for (Future<HttpResponse> futureResponse : futureResponseList) {
                /* This will cause a block. However We have already submitted
                all of our requests. So if we block once we should expect to see less
                often blocks when reading from the "future" responses;
                 */
                    httpResponseList.add(futureResponse.get());
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                System.out.println("Caught " + e);
            }finally {
                httpClient.close();
            }
            return httpResponseList.iterator();
        }
    }).count();
    System.out.println("Final result count : " + results);
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // Init the spark context
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("AsyncSparkJob"));
    // Create the spark job
    AsyncSparkJob asj = new AsyncSparkJob(sc);
    asj.run(args[0]);
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

}

Is this a valid use cases ?

Comment: Hi guys, I wonder if you have any feedback about this topic? Did you implement this use case as purposed in the question above or decided to go on a diff direction?